How to use Spotify refreshToken
I'm using nextjs14.2 and typescript.
I am creating a music web using Spotify API and currently having a problem with the authentication process.
trying to refresh the token, but the code provided by spotify is node.js and seems to be a bit old version.
I'm trying to handle it using a route handler.
How do I change this code below?
Reference link
    app.get('/refresh_token', function(req, res) {
    
      var refresh_token = req.query.refresh_token;
      var authOptions = {
        url: 'https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token',
        headers: {
          'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
          'Authorization': 'Basic ' + (new Buffer.from(client_id + ':' +        client_secret).toString('base64'))
        },
        form: {
          grant_type: 'refresh_token',
          refresh_token: refresh_token
        },
        json: true
      };
    
      request.post(authOptions, function(error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
          var access_token = body.access_token,
              refresh_token = body.refresh_token;
          res.send({
            'access_token': access_token,
            'refresh_token': refresh_token
          });
        }
      });
    });

I want the code to work without error and get the access_token and refresh_token and save them back to the database.

you can get the refresh token in express in here

Thank yoy, but it didn't work for me..
